# Are these two Abel's criteria for uniform convergence different?

Tags: real-analysis

I wonder what differences are between the folowwing two versions of Abel's criteria for uniform convergence:

From [Elementary classical analysis by Marsden and Hoffman](http://books.google.com/books?id=mMBY5jdjGfoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=marsden%20classical%20analysis&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=z79TTtFmx_DSAf_P-eIF&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6wEwAA#v=onepage&q=Abel%27s%20Test.%20%20sequence%20of%20functions%20which%20are%20decreasing;%20that%20is,&f=false):

> **Abel's Test**. Let $A \subset R^n$ and $\phi_n: A
>  \rightarrow R$ be a sequence of functions which are decreasing; that
>   is, $\phi_{n+1}(x) \leq \phi_n(x)$ for each $x \in A$. Suppose there
>   is a constant $M$ such that$|\phi_n(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in A$ and
>   all $n$. If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $A$, then
>   so does $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_n(x)f_n(x)$.

From  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_uniform_convergence_test):

> **Abel's uniform convergence test**. Let $\{g_n\}$ be a uniformly
>   bounded sequence of real-valued **continuous** functions on a set $E$ such
>   that $g_{n+1}(x) \leq  g_n(x)$ for all $x ∈ E$ and positive integers $n$,
>   and let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real-valued functions such that the
>   series $\displaystyle\sum f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $E$. Then $\displaystyle\sum f_n(x)g_n(x)
>   $converges uniformly on $E$.

1. Is the additional requirement of continuity for a sequence of
   functions in Wikipedia the only difference? If not, what else?
2. Is this continuity unnecessary and can be ignored as in Marsden's? If
   yes, is Marsden's a more general version? Or do you have a different one?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Doesn't Marsden specify what $f_n$ is? The assumption of continuity in Wiki's version is superfluous, as well as the assumption that $f_n$ be real-valued, they could be complex-valued as well. I see no other difference except that assumption. There are many of results of this flavor, see e.g. [Dirichlet's criterion](http://eom.springer.de/d/d032820.htm) and [Dedekind's criterion](http://eom.springer.de/d/d030520.htm) for two of them.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks! Does Marsden? I cannot find it.

Comment: I'm asking. I don't know. Probably he has a universal assumption what $f$ and $f_n$ is supposed to mean. Google doesn't let me look and I never held that book in my hands.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that continuity is necessary.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. The uniform convergence of the series implies that there exists $n$ such that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n}^m f_k(x)\right|<\varepsilon \ \ \ \text{ for all } x\in A, m>n.
$$
The key to the proof is "summation by parts": we have 
$$
\sum_{k=n}^m\phi_k(x)f_k(x)=\phi_m(x)\sum_{k=n}^mf_k(x)-\sum_{k=n}^m(\phi_{k+1}(x)-\phi_k(x))\sum_{j=n}^kf_j(x).
$$
Then

\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=n}^m\phi_k(x)f_k(x)\right|&\leq|\phi_m(x)|\,\left|\sum_{k=n}^mf_k(x)\right|+\sum_{k=n}^m\,|\phi_{k+1}(x)-\phi_k(x)|\,\left|\sum_{j=n}^kf_j(x)\right|\\
&\leq M\varepsilon + \varepsilon \sum_{k=n}^m\,\phi_{k}(x)-\phi_{k+1}(x)
=M\varepsilon + \varepsilon(\phi_n(x)-\phi_{m+1}(x))\\
&<3M\varepsilon.
\end{align}

Comment: May be for an experienced mathematicans it's obviuous but I just wanted to add that we talk about the space of real valued functions which is complete w.r.t $\Vert \cdot\Vert_{\infty}$. This is necessary to conclude that a Cauchy sequence of functions is convergent.